# Python SharedMemomery concurrent read and write to array from multiple processes

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, locking, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

## Problem Statement

I have an array shared across multiple processes (numpy array shared via multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory) to avoid Queues, Pipes, or any serialization overhead.
I have multiple processes r<sub>i</sub> , that only read the entire shared array but do not write to it. Additionally, I have multiple processes w<sub>i</sub> , that only write (but do not read) to the shared array:

1. Multiple processes r<sub>i</sub>:

   - r<sub>i</sub> only reads the entire shared array
   - r<sub>i</sub> does not perform any write operation
2. Multiple processes w<sub>i</sub>:

   - w<sub>i</sub> only writes to exclusive indices of the shared array
   - w<sub>i</sub> does not need to read the item, which it is (over-)writing to (so only `array[i,j]=k`, but no `array[i,j]+=k` - is this called atomic?)
   - no two w<sub>i</sub> write to the same index
3. r<sub>i</sub> and w<sub>i</sub> are long running processes, so they perform their corresponding read and write operations continuously and repeatedly over a certain time period (different w<sub>i</sub> read from different websockets and write data to the shared array s.t. all updated data is available at once for each r<sub>i</sub>, which performs some calculations based on the entire data set...)

What happens, if r<sub>i</sub> reads the shared array whilst any w<sub>i</sub> concurrently writes to it? Is unexpected read behavior possible in this case? (That's at least what I guess...)

## My thoughts so far

### Assumptions

1. A1: Multiple concurrent read-only operations from different processes (r<sub>i</sub>) is safe without any locking or synchronization mechanism.
2. A2: Each w<sub>i</sub> writes to a different index of the shared array, so I assume, that no locking or synchronization mechanism is needed, when multiple w<sub>i</sub> write concurrently.

### Design

Based on A1 and A2, I only need locking, if any process of r<sub>i</sub> and any process of w<sub>i</sub> operate at the same time.
I guess, locking between any two processes within the set of r<sub>i</sub> or any two processes within the set of w<sub>i</sub> is not necessary, as long as no two processes across those two sets operate at the same time.

Basically, I want to allow any write operation concurrently as long as no read operation is performed and to prevent any write operation if any read operation is performed in order to avoid any problems during the read operation (i.e. reading garbage/undefined val) - if this is necessary at all?.

### Code

```py
import itertools
import time
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, Event, Process, Semaphore

import attrs
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt


class ReadWriteLock:
    """Synchronize read and write operations of shared memory.

    Block any write operation if any read operation is ongoing and vice versa.
    Concurrent write operations are allowed. Concurrent read operations are allowed.
    Call acquire_read() before, and release_read() after reading from shared memory.
    Call acquire_write() before, and release_write() after writing to shared memory.
    """

    __slots__ = ["_sem_read", "_sem_write", "_is_writable", "_is_readable"]

    def __init__(self):
        # keep track of processes reading from shared memory
        self._sem_read = Semaphore(value=0)

        # keep track of processes writing to shared memory
        self._sem_write = Semaphore(value=0)

        # signal if shared memory can be written to
        self._is_writable = Event()
        self._is_writable.set()

        # signal if shared memory can be read from
        self._is_readable = Event()
        self._is_readable.set()

    def acquire_read(self):
        """Call acquire_read() before reading shared memory.
        Blocks if any process is currently writing to shared memory"""
        self._is_writable.clear()  # signal that shared memory is not writable
        self._is_readable.wait()  # wait until any write operation has finished
        self._sem_read.release()  # increment count of semaphore/ reading processes

    def release_read(self):
        """Call release_read() after reading shared memory."""
        self._sem_read.acquire(block=False)  # decrement count of semaphore (reading)

        if not self._sem_read.acquire(block=False):
            # counter is at 0, no process is currently reading (counter cannot fall below 0)
            self._is_writable.set()
        else:
            # counter is not at 0, so there are still processes reading.
            # We revert acquire() call done within the if condition
            self._sem_read.release()

    def acquire_write(self):
        """Call acquire_write() before writing to shared memory.
        Blocks if any process is currently reading from shared memory."""
        self._is_readable.clear()  # signal that shared memory is not readable
        self._is_writable.wait()  # wait until any read operation has finished
        self._sem_write.release()  # increment count semaphore/ writing processes

    def release_write(self):
        """Call release_write() after writing to shared memory."""
        self._sem_write.acquire(block=False)  # decrement count of semaphore (writing)

        if not self._sem_write.acquire(block=False):
            # counter at 0, no process is currently writing
            self._is_readable.set()
        else:
            # still some processes writing to shared memory, so revert acquire() call in if condition
            self._sem_write.release()


@attrs.define
class SharedArray:
    """Array, which can be shared via multiple processes.

    Writing and reading via index can be performed as usual. To access the entire array (read-only), use array.data.
    Multiple processes can concurrently read from SharedArray. Multiple process can concurrently write to SharedArray.
    It's the user's responsibility, that no two process write to the same index.
    Writing to SharedArray will block until no read operation is performed on SharedArray, and vice versa.
    """

    shape: tuple | int
    dtype: npt.DTypeLike

    read_write_lock: ReadWriteLock = attrs.field(default=ReadWriteLock(), init=False)
    shm: shared_memory.SharedMemory | None = attrs.field(default=None)
    raw: np.ndarray = attrs.field(init=False)

    shm_name: str = attrs.field(default=None, init=False)

    def bytesize(self) -> int:
        return int(np.prod(self.shape) * self.dtype.itemsize)

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.dtype = np.dtype(self.dtype)
        self.shape = self.shape if isinstance(self.shape, tuple) else (self.shape,)

        if self.shm is None:
            self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=self.bytesize())

        self.shm_name = self.shm.name

        self.raw = np.ndarray(shape=self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, buffer=self.shm.buf)

    @classmethod
    def from_arr(cls, array: np.ndarray, shm: shared_memory.SharedMemory | None = None):
        f_array = cls(array.shape, array.dtype, shm)
        f_array.raw[:] = array[:]

        assert f_array.shm.size == array.nbytes
        assert f_array.raw.nbytes == array.nbytes
        return f_array

    @property
    def data(self) -> np.ndarray:
        try:
            self.read_write_lock.acquire_read()
            data = self.raw[:]
        finally:
            self.read_write_lock.release_read()
        return data

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            self.read_write_lock.acquire_read()
            data = self.raw[item]
        finally:
            self.read_write_lock.release_read()
        return data

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            self.read_write_lock.acquire_write()
            self.raw[key] = value
        finally:
            self.read_write_lock.release_write()

    def __getstate__(self):
        self.shm_name = self.shm.name
        return {
            "shape": self.shape,
            "dtype": self.dtype,
            "shm_name": self.shm_name,
            "read_write_lock": self.read_write_lock,
        }

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.shape = state["shape"]
        self.dtype = state["dtype"]
        self.shm_name = state["shm_name"]
        self.read_write_lock = state["read_write_lock"]

        self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=self.shm_name, create=False)
        self.raw = np.ndarray(shape=self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, buffer=self.shm.buf)

    def close(self) -> None:
        self.shm.close()

    def unlink(self) -> None:
        self.shm.unlink()


def read_proc(arr: SharedArray) -> None:
    # simulate long-running process
    for _ in range(5):
        data = arr.data
        # do something
        print(data)
        time.sleep(0.05)
    arr.close()


def write_proc(arr: SharedArray, idx: tuple[int, int], val: float) -> None:
    # simulate long-running process
    for _ in range(5):
        arr[idx] = val
        time.sleep(0.01)
    arr.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    shared_arr = SharedArray.from_arr(np.arange(4).reshape((2, 2)))

    r_i = [Process(target=read_proc, args=(shared_arr,)) for _ in range(2)]
    w_i = [
        Process(target=write_proc, args=(shared_arr, t, i + 10))
        for i, t in enumerate(itertools.product(range(2), range(2)))
    ]

    for r in r_i:
        r.start()
    for w in w_i:
        w.start()

    for r in r_i:
        r.join()
    for w in w_i:
        w.join()

    shared_arr.close()
    shared_arr.unlink()
```

Not sure, if above code (especially `ReadWriteLock`) could run into deadlock or starvation of readers or writers.

I'm not sure, if my code makes sense at all, if I'm overengineering here (e.g. if concurrent read and write to shared memory really is a problem...) or if my assumptions are right. So, any feedback, hints or recommendations are very much appreciated!

Comment: locking the file would ensure that data is read sequentially.  However, this comes at the expense of slowing the process considerably.

Comment: would this be more suitable to an in memory database, like `sqlite3` ?